# Gradescope automatic match of pages to problems

Tags: grading

I used Gradescope with the Instructor upload setting for a paper-based exam that was scanned in bulk. I included a template of the exam with name, ID, and problem regions specified. The exams scanned correctly and were split by student correctly.

However, the pages were not matched to problems automatically, and I don't see any way even to do that manually.  This has worked fine when I use the Student upload setting.  Am I missing something about how to get pages and problems matched with Instructor upload?

Comment: This has worked for me in the past.  Did you set up the template with all the questions and answer boxes defined before uploading the PDFs of the exams?  Do all the exams have the same number of pages with the answer boxes in the same places?

Comment: Yes, I had all that set up.  In the end, I copied the assignment, uploaded the exams to the new assignment and went through the process of splitting by name and then matching pages to problems.  After that it worked.  I think the central office that scanned and uploaded the exams originally must have skipped a step or stopped before getting to that step  .